# Cannot enable CORS in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to enable CORS on an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I am very frustrated.

I've already tried several snippets and none worked for me. This was my last attempt.

Startup.cs, "ConfigureServices" method.

```
 services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>  p.AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()));
```

Startup.cs, "Configure" method.

```
 app.UseCors("AllowAll");
 app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

In my Controller I used this

```
  [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Route("cors")]       
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Ok";

    }
}
```

I am getting CORS issues on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I am using Angular. Maybe it's something to do with Angular.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this as I am having exactly the same problem. I am also using Angular. I am using Angular 7... This is very frustrating...

Comment: @notExactlyAHero Have you found any solution?

Comment: @coolblue2000Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is one important thing to know in order to make CORS work: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin

From [the documentation at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-cors-with-cors-middleware),

> If the response doesn't include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>   header, the cross-origin request fails. Specifically, the browser
>   disallows the request. Even if the server returns a successful
>   response, the browser doesn't make the response available to the
>   client app.

If this header is present then generally your config should work. 
You can verify this using fiddler.

There is one option to "Disable Same Origin" policy from the chrome and firefox.  Please [refer this blog](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/) for checking how to disable it.

But please note that this would make your browser vulnerable, this may be advisable to get it working during development, but not recommended at all for production scenarios.